# Not able to get dataStreamName : from_activities from google datasource list to fetch Calories

Tags: java, google-fit, google-fit-api

I am using google fit datasource API
`https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources` to get the data sources.

For calories, I was using below data stream:

```
dataStreamName : from_activities
dataStreamId : derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:from_activities
```

But now, I am not getting **from_activities** data stream from `https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources` datasource API list.

Instead I am getting below data stream for calories:

```
dataStreamName : merge_calories_expended
dataStreamId : derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:merge_calories_expended
```

**So, is there any changes made from google side that suddenly I am not getting `dataStreamName : from_activities` data stream from data source list?**

If yes, is it good to use `dataStreamName : merge_calories_expended` data stream to fetch the calories data? What differences are there between these 2 (from_activities and merge_calories_expended) data steams?

Answer (score 0):

The Fit platform stopped populating the `from_activities` stream earlier this year, so you should have seen the change more than six months ago.

Yes, `merge_calories_expended` is probably the right thing to use. It contains a merged view of the user's calories expended, identical to that which is shown in the Fit app.

Comment: Do we have any official documentation or communication from google about this?
I was not able to find the documentation related to this change from https://developers.google.com/fit/android/releases